# How to securely store sql files apache server

Tags: php, apache, security

So, I'm writing a php script which will be tied to a cron job that will backup my site's db on a regular basis. The db will get saved to a new sql file daily just incase anything unfortunate should happen to the live version. I am aware of how bad it would be for someone to be able to get a hold of one of these files, exposing both the db structure and user email addresses (passwords are encrypted).

I am not extraordinarily security savvy, and this is one of those things you HAVE to get right the first time around. I'm not to prideful to admit when it's best to ask for help so I figured I'd inquire with the trusted Stack Overflow community. (I realize it's likely there is a question similar to this somewhere, but I have been unable to find it).

What steps do I need to take to make sure these files can't be accessed? Note, it is an Apache server. Is it enough to store them in a directory outside of the root which is limited to group read/write (no public read)? Or is it necessary to password protect the directory or even encrypt the actual files? I'd really rather not if I don't have to (encrypt the files), it would just make it more of a pain to use them, but if it's needed...

Also relevant, access to these files is NOT being built into an application interface. I don't need or want to have them accessible by an http request. FTP only. So my question isn't regarding any password protection of a UI.

Thank you all so much for your time!

Comment: store them outside the web root, thats all

Answer (score 0):

**Storing on the server**

If you must, store them outside of the web root and download them with something like `rsync` over `ssh`.

**Best option (assuming you're running MySQL)**

Don't store them on the server, but rather run a cron on your local machine and use `ssh` and `MySQL` to do the dump to your local system. That way there is no ominous file someone can have that contains all of your data (unless of course your local network is compromised).

**Another option (again another example with MySQL)**

You might also look into doing [database replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html) with your local machine by setting up a local MySQL server.

Comment: if some one has access to the file on the server, they have access to the db on the server.

Comment: @Dagon not necessarily. There may be a variety of different users on the system. Shared hosting, Shared VPS, Dedicated Managed, and Self-managed systems have a variety of different user accounts and accesses. If someone has ROOT on your system then they have access to the system. In fact MySQL can sometimes have it's own user account that runs the server. That way they can administer access to the database. Never assume anything about a server setup unless it's unplugged from the web.

Comment: @Dagon in some instances someone like a DBA would have access to the database and someone like a web designer would have access to the same system. They should have two different access realms, but if you start storing a file in a location where it can be retrieved remotely you cross those realms.